# Texture not rendering in Cycles engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, lighting, glass

I have a scene which I have made:

[image]

But when i go to render it in Cycles. The table loses it's texture (which I custom made through Blender's shading workspace.

[image]

Why is my table texture disappearing in the render?

Here is the blend file if you'd like to investigate:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the *Outliner*, you have an object that is disabled in preview but enabled in render, disable it in render as well:

[image]